# Is there any way to put custom button in antd image preview's operation panel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

[image: Add custom button here]

I want to put some button that have functionality to download or share the previewed image. Is there any possible way to achieve this?

I've search for some answer and read the documentation but found solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, `antd` v5.1.5 does **not** support it. There is [issue](https://github.com/react-component/image/issues/113) to request a custom or extended preview operations feature.

From the source code of `rc-image`, we know the preview operations are defined internally and doesn't support custom and extension. See [v5.13.0/src/Operations.tsx#L58](https://github.com/react-component/image/blob/v5.13.0/src/Operations.tsx#L58)

Only these operations:

```
const tools = [
    {
      icon: close,
      onClick: onClose,
      type: 'close',
    },
    {
      icon: zoomIn,
      onClick: onZoomIn,
      type: 'zoomIn',
      disabled: scale === MAX_SCALE,
    },
    {
      icon: zoomOut,
      onClick: onZoomOut,
      type: 'zoomOut',
      disabled: scale === MIN_SCALE,
    },
    {
      icon: rotateRight,
      onClick: onRotateRight,
      type: 'rotateRight',
    },
    {
      icon: rotateLeft,
      onClick: onRotateLeft,
      type: 'rotateLeft',
    },
  ]
```